# Getting errors while converting from Clipper using Harbour

Tags: clipper

I have created a test project in clipper.

Here is the code for test.prg

```
store space(1) to mT
@ 10,10 say "hellow Time :" get mT pict "!"
read
```

Here is the generated hbp file code:

```
-3rd=hbide_version=1.0
-3rd=hbide_type=Executable
-3rd=hbide_title=test
-3rd=hbide_location=d:\hcjs\
-3rd=hbide_workingfolder=
-3rd=hbide_destinationfolder=
-3rd=hbide_output=test
-3rd=hbide_launchparams=
-3rd=hbide_launchprogram=
-3rd=hbide_backupfolder=
-3rd=hbide_xhb=NO
-3rd=hbide_xpp=NO
-3rd=hbide_clp=YES

-inc
-mt
-w3
-es2
-gtwvg
-gui
-lhbwin
-lxhb

test.prg
```

I have followed the following steps:

```
1. Open Project
2. I select test.hbp
3. Right-click on Select an environment
4. Select MinGW
5. Again Right Click then Build And Launch
```

Conversion is not successful. I get some errors. Errors are as follows:

```
1. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'mT'
2. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'GETLIST'
3. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'GETLIST'
4. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'GETLIST'
5. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'GETLIST'
6. Warning: Ambiguous Reference 'GETLIST'

Sorry, cannot launch project because of errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the way, it's a warning, not an error. the program should work just fine.

to remove the warning, add these lines to the top of the file :

```
LOCAL GetList := {} 
LOCAL mT
```

Comment: To the top of the function where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Didn´t you forget to put FUNCTION MAIN() in the first line of your main program? It´s mandatory in [x]Harbour.
Example:

```
FUNCTION MAIN()
store space(1) to mT
@ 10,10 say "hellow Time :" get mT pict "!"
read
```

If you wanna just make a test like this you don´t need to make a so complicated hbp file to compile it. Just call hbmk2 and the name of the prg file like that:

`HBMK2 HELLO.PRG`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't have any knowledge of clipper. One of my friend is a clipper programmer and he asked me to get some help, so i posted it here. BTW, I hope, it will be helpful to someone in future.